# Initialise non-serializable object that reads from HDFS on the workers

Tags: apache-spark

I need to use a non-serializable Java object from inside a map operation. If I try to initialise it first on the Driver I get the "Task not serializable" error. The best option would be declare it for each parition, but the initialisation of the object reads some files from HDFS. To be able to do that, I would need the sc.hadoopConfiguration, variable that seems to be not available on the workers (NullPointerException).

Can I read from HDFS on the workers side? If so, I would be able to initialise the object for each partition using mapPartitions. If not, what is the best approach?

Comment: How much data are you reading from HDFS to configure your object? I will often just collect the configuration data in the driver and create an Array of Strings. I use Scala, but I create a singleton object and anywhere in my executor code I use the object I pass in the Array of Strings as an argument. If it hasn't been initialized, it initializes itself with the array of strings; if it's already been initialized it ignores the array of strings and just does whatever you wanted it to do. Doing it like this, I don't even have to worry about per partition -- it only happens once per executor

Comment: Good approach. I will try to merge this with the answer provided by @zsxwing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `sc.hadoopConfiguration` with `SerializableWritable` and use it in your codes like this:

```
  val hadoopConf = new SerializableWritable(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
  sc.parallelize(1 to 1000, 4).mapPartitions { iter =>
    val conf = hadoopConf.value
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly. Do you know the reason the hadoop configuration is not passed to the workers?

Comment: It's because Spark may run in other platforms and doesn't need the hadoop configuration for them. By the way, it should be called `executor` instead of `worker`. `worker` has another meaning in Spark.